# Reusing toolbar layout with drawer and navigation view

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

As I am very new to Android, I have some confusion for standard way of using layouts in Android. Basically, I am an iOS developer. I have created a new project with NavigationDrawerView template. Now I have to create another activities with toolbar and drawer with navigation view. Basically, I want to design a layout having toolbar, drawer and navigation view, which can be just included in an activity and content can be designed in the newly created activity. Can anyone suggest the best way to do this. I hope every one aware of the default template design for navigation drawer view. So that I am not including the code here. If anybody wants to see the code, let me know.

Comment: you can use fragments, use a frame in main activity and switch between fragments as your requirement so you are in a single activity and switch between fragments as your need. every view is easily accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to use following xml files:
content_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.android.MainActivity"//you main activity
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

</RelativeLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/actionbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/navDrawerbg"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And Make main java file i.e `mainactivity extends AppcompatActivity and  implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Declare global varible:

```
private Context mContext;
         private static FragmentManager mManager;
                Fragment fragment = null;
```

Create below method after oncreate

```
private void initUI() {

        if (fragment != null) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();

        }

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Intiate the fragmentview

```
private void initiateFragmentView() {
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
```

And call above method in the oncreate method after setcontentview()

```
 mManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragment = new Home();

                mContext = this;
                initUI();
```

Call your fragments when drawer itemselected

```
@Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

                 //Your fragment
                fragment = new Home();
                initiateFragmentView();

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_xyz) {

                fragment = new xyz();
                initiateFragmentView();


            } else if (id == R.id.nav_abc) {

                fragment = new abc();
                initiateFragmentView();

            }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
```